# Firefox addon: How to show notification bar at the top of the webpage?

Tags: firefox-addon, notifications

Can someone tell me how to popup a notification message inside a firefox addon like the one that Firefox displays to offer to store passwords? I am not talking about the alert boxes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a [notification box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL%3anotificationbox) and [notifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL%3anotification).

See this previous question for some example code.
[How are firefox notifications implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737628/how-are-firefox-notifications-implemented)